# count number of rows in php file that is called by ajax

Tags: php

I am having the following php code that is called by the ajax and is shown in the page once the input field on the page is being changed. Everything is working fine but I can not get the variable for the number of rows in the query2.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'name' ,'pass', 'db');

$kw=$_GET['kw'];
$schicht=$_GET['schicht'];
$field_id=$_GET['field_id'];

if(!$db) {

    echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

if(1==1) {

$query1 = $db->query("UPDATE dienstplan SET schicht= '".$schicht."' WHERE field_id='".$field_id."'");

}
if($query1) 
{
echo '<div id="managementfields1" class="fieldslist2">';
while ($result = $query1 ->fetch_object()) {

$schichtcheck = $result->schicht;

$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM codes WHERE lcfruh='$schichtcheck' OR lcmittag='$schichtcheck' OR lcmitlcspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcmitshspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcspaet='$schichtcheck' OR shmittag='$schichtcheck' OR shmitshspat='$schichtcheck' OR shmitlcspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcspaet='$schichtcheck' OR lcnacht='$schichtcheck' OR lcteildienst='$schichtcheck' OR shfruh='$schichtcheck' OR shspaet='$schichtcheck' OR shnacht='$schichtcheck' OR shteildienst='$schichtcheck' OR frei='$schichtcheck' OR modkod='$schichtcheck' OR lcshteil='$schichtcheck' OR shlcteil='$schichtcheck");

$rowcount = /// i need here number of rows from the query2;

if($rowcount>0) {
$color="white";
} elseif if($rowcount<1){
$color="red";
}

echo '<p><input name="schicht[]" style="background-color:'.$color.'" type="text" value="'.$result->schicht.'"></p>';
}
echo '</div>;
}
else {
echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
}
}   
?>
```

Comment: Does `$rowcount = $query2->num_rows;` not work?

Comment: for $rowcount = $query2->num_rows; i am getting Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: for $result=mysqli_num_rows(query6) i am getting notice Use of undefined constant query6 - assumed 'query6' in

Comment: Have you try to tried a `var_dump($query2);` to check that your query is correct?

Answer (score 2):

After a quick look, you have error at, missing a single quote:

```
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM codes WHERE lcfruh='$schichtcheck' OR lcmittag='$schichtcheck' OR lcmitlcspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcmitshspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcspaet='$schichtcheck' OR shmittag='$schichtcheck' OR shmitshspat='$schichtcheck' OR shmitlcspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcspaet='$schichtcheck' OR lcnacht='$schichtcheck' OR lcteildienst='$schichtcheck' OR shfruh='$schichtcheck' OR shspaet='$schichtcheck' OR shnacht='$schichtcheck' OR shteildienst='$schichtcheck' OR frei='$schichtcheck' OR modkod='$schichtcheck' OR lcshteil='$schichtcheck' OR shlcteil='$schichtcheck");
```

Shall be:

```
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM codes WHERE lcfruh='$schichtcheck' OR lcmittag='$schichtcheck' OR lcmitlcspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcmitshspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcspaet='$schichtcheck' OR shmittag='$schichtcheck' OR shmitshspat='$schichtcheck' OR shmitlcspat='$schichtcheck' OR lcspaet='$schichtcheck' OR lcnacht='$schichtcheck' OR lcteildienst='$schichtcheck' OR shfruh='$schichtcheck' OR shspaet='$schichtcheck' OR shnacht='$schichtcheck' OR shteildienst='$schichtcheck' OR frei='$schichtcheck' OR modkod='$schichtcheck' OR lcshteil='$schichtcheck' OR shlcteil='$schichtcheck'");
```

Comment: Ajax called php script is difficult to verify, as the result is not visible on browser. ;). One should invoke it directly to test first.